# Tomcat 7 home page not showing up

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I have ubuntu 12.04 and I installed tomcat 7 as

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

When I access the tomcat home page using localhost:8080  it works fine and displayed the page.

Then as a next step i created a tomcat7 instance using

sudo tomcat7-instance-create -p 8180 -c 8105 /opt/tomcat7-oldapp

Then I started the tomcat 7 instance using

```
/bin/startup.sh
```

The following command:

```
sudo lsof -i :8180
```

shows the output:

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    5673 root   37u  IPv6  27902      0t0  TCP *:8180 (LISTEN)
```

which clearly means that tomcat 7 instance is listening on port 8180

but when I try to access the homepage using  localhost:8180  using a browser, Firefox says connection timed out. The server is taking too long to respond.

Is it because tomcat 7 instance runs under root user while tomcat running on 8080 runs under tomcat7 user?

If yes, how do I run tomcat 7 instance under tomcat7 user?

If no, what could be the problem?

### UPDATE

When I install tomcat 7 manually, home page does not appear as in the case of tomcat instance

I am kind of convinced now that the real problem is when tomcat 7 is installed as apt-get , it runs under tomcat7 user and group while when its instance is installed as well as when tomcat 7 is installed manually, it is running under root user. Therefore I am not able to access a page via a browser. For manual installation i created /etc/init.d/tomcat755 file and defined TOMCAT_USER=tomcat and TOMCAT_GROUP=tomcat but to no avail. It continues running under root.

Comment: not really anything to do with java is it

Comment: If you get 404, tomcat is responding, it just can't find a file to use as home page. If you get "cannot connect to server", then tomcat is not responding

Comment: @ScaryWombat Java home is set and both tomcats use that /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle

Comment: @BackSlash my apologies I am not sure if its 404. Firefox says connection timed out. The server is taking too long to respond.

Comment: check what -c has to do here. I guess there's some default timeout

Comment: check if http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html helps

Comment: @jsjunkie -c specifies the shutdown port

Comment: I am kind of convinced now that the real problem is when tomcat 7 is installed as apt-get , it runs under tomcat7 user and group while when its instance is installed as well as when tomcat 7 is installed manually, it is running under root user. Therefore I am not able to access a page via a browser. For manual installation i created /etc/init.d/tomcat755 file and defined TOMCAT_USER=tomcat and TOMCAT_GROUP=tomcat but to no avail. It continues running under root.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting 404 that means Tomcat is up and running, only the thing is that you are not opening correct page. are you trying to open http: //127.0.0.1:8180 ?

Comment: my apologies I am not sure if its 404. Firefox says connection timed out. The server is taking too long to respond.